# DB2 SQL Finding rows with a gap of 1 minute with other rows

Tags: sql, db2, series, db2-luw

DB2 v10.5.0.5 on Linux

I have a table of something like:

```
LOG_IN              | LOG_OFF
-----------------------------------------
2017-01-22 08:00:00 | 2017-01-22 09:00:00
2017-01-22 09:01:00 | 2017-01-22 10:00:00
2017-01-22 10:00:00 | 2017-01-22 10:15:00
2017-01-22 10:15:00 | 2017-01-22 10:45:00
2017-01-22 11:00:00 | 2017-01-22 11:29:00
2017-01-22 11:30:00 | 2017-01-22 12:00:00
```

I would like to select the rows where it has a gap of 1 minute with other rows.

Desired result:

```
LOG_IN              | LOG_OFF
-----------------------------------------
2017-01-22 08:00:00 | 2017-01-22 09:00:00
2017-01-22 09:01:00 | 2017-01-22 10:00:00
2017-01-22 11:00:00 | 2017-01-22 11:29:00
2017-01-22 11:30:00 | 2017-01-22 12:00:00
```

Comment: Is your Db2-database on mainframe (z/OS) or i-series (OS/400) or Linux/Unix/Windows?  What version is your Db2-server? Different versions have OLAP windowing functions.

Comment: DB2 v10.5.0.5 on Linux.

Comment: In Db2, what is the column datatype of LOG_IN and LOG_OFF ?

Comment: Both columns are of type TIMESTAMP

Comment: I marked question down because I don't like that you dont have any results between 10 and 10:45.  Maybe I was logged in at that period???

Comment: No results there based on the criteria which is having a 1 minute gap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Db2 you can use [date / time arithmetics](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023457.html) to do that. Without testing, something like this should work:

```
select log_in, log_off
from accountlogs
where log_off - log_in = 1 minute
```

Instead of `1 minute` you can also use other values or `<` instead of `=`.

If you want to find gaps with other rows, you need to self-join:

```
select al1.log_in, al1.log_off, al2.log_in, al2.log_off
from accountlogs al1, accountlogs al2
where al1.log_off - al2.log_in < 1 minute
```

The above would fit your desired result and also returns data of the matching other row.

Comment: Hi Henrik. Duration gap comparison must be with **other** rows.

Comment: Then it is a self-join, but the arithmetics is the same. Leave out the columns that you don't need

Comment: I don't know what made me do all the suffering in not thinking of a simple join.  Lost hours.  Thank you Henrik.  My final solution though is timestampdiff(4, char(al2.LOG_OFF - al1.LOG_IN)) = -1

Answer (score 0):

Given your version of LUW, the [`LAG`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023461.html) function should also be available:

```
SELECT log_in, log_off
FROM (SELECT log_in, log_off, (LAG(log_off) OVER (ORDER BY log_in)) - 1 MINUTE AS previous
      FROM Data) d
WHERE log_in = previous
```

<kbd>[Fiddle Example (SQL Server)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bad6e/4/0)</kbd>

This **might** be faster than a self-join (you'll need to check): the date math will cause the optimizer to ignore any indices, which may be a significant performance penalty on large tables.  However, note that this limits you to exactly *one* previous row, which may not be what you want (which would require a self-join to find all matching rows).

Comment: Yes, I needed to find all matching rows for the same day and a match can be not necessarily the previous.